# Serverless Deploy to Different AWS Accounts

Tags: terraform, serverless-framework, serverless, aws-serverless

I have serverless project with bunch of terraform resource creation.
I would like to deploy Lambda functions in **one AWS account** and as part of serverless deploy, it can create API Gateway endpoints (pointing to lambda functions).

I would like to API Gateway to be created in **Another AWS Account**. Is it possible do purely in serverless. If not what are the options ?

Comment: Sounds, like the you should split your resources creation to two scripts. Each of script must be executed under dedicated AWS Account (--profile <AWS Account>). Lambda ARN may be used for configuring API Gateway.

Comment: What do you mean by script in serverless project ? Could you explain

Comment: I mean, that you would need to register two providers, where you set the first AWS acc as profile to one provider and the second AWS acc to the second provider. (https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/providers.html#alias-multiple-provider-instances) Then you need to set which provider must be used in resource/module. (resource Lambda - provider with First AWS Account, resource API - provider with the second ASW Account)

Comment: Why you would have Lambda and API Gateway in two different regions? What are you trying to achieve. It really sounds like an antipattern!

Comment: It is requirement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try an EventBridge approach. You should be able to access functions securely, without creating complex dual-account ARNs, Policy Scripts and permissions:

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');

function notifyMarketingTeam(email) {
 const eventBridge = new AWS.EventBridge({key:XXXXX,secret:XXXX region: 'us-east-1' }); 

 return eventBridge.putEvents({
   Entries: [
     {
       EventBusName: 'marketing',
       Source: 'acme.newsletter.campaign',
       DetailType: 'UserSignUp',
       Detail: `{ "E-Mail": "${email}" }`,
   },
   ]
 }).promise()
}
```